# RSS issue with Lyften Bloggie component for Joomla

Tags: joomla, rss, atom-feed

I am using a component called [Lyften Bloggie](http://www.lyften.com/projects/lyften-bloggie.html) for my website which is built up on Joomla. But there is an issue with the RSS feeds. When I click on the feed buton it is re-loading the same blog page and nothing is displayed. When I checked it with Firebug it is showing 301 error in the net console. I don't know what is happening. I disabled the SEF URLs in Joomla and the same issue is persisting. When I am opening in chrome, it is showing the feed source, but again in feed validator it is showing the same 301 error.

Comment: may I suggest you contact the developer of the component ;)

Comment: already done...no reply from their part :(

Answer (score -1):

What version of Joomla are using and what version of LyftenBloggie?
Looking at the site for the component, I don't see much activity.

To debug your issue have you looked at console output?  Perhaps there's some interference from another component?

Comment: It is showing 301 moved permanently error in Firebug console.this is the link http://healingstreamsusa.org/blog.html Please click on the two rss links at the bottom

Comment: Both of these urls are non-functional.  If you look at the source(in Firefox) They are highlighted in red...this indicates something wrong.  When you look closer they both have the "url" attribute which is unrecognised.  As I remember Lyftenbloggie is a plugin.  I would look into the plugin and find where these urls are created.  Can you post back this code?

Comment: Sorry, had another blog component in mind.  Lyftenbloggie not a plugin but a component.

Comment: I had a copy of Lyften on my server, having looked I can't see anything that would write in the "url" attribute into the link.  Are you using 1.1.0?  It looks like RSS was overhauled in that version.

Comment: No I am actually using 1.1.2 .Any fixes for this issue ?

Comment: From what I can see they thought they had fixed it in 1.1.  I think the most important thing here is that you have already tried to communicate with the developer and been ignored.  For me this is the most important part of choosing any component I'm going to use.